# High and low bytes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I try to find low/high bytes from a number like that:

```
If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
If TextBox1.Value < 65535 Then
Dim lowByte As Byte
Dim highByte As Byte
Dim number As Long
Dim textBoxValueLong As Long
textBoxValueLong = Val(TextBox1.Value)
lowByte = textBoxValueLong And &HFF&
highByte = Fix(textBoxValueLong / 256)
number = highByte * 256 + lowByte
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = highByte
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = lowByte
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = number
End If
End If
```

But if number is lower than -255, I have an overflow error in this string `highByte = Fix(textBoxValueLong / 256)`

What is wrong?

UPD: If I use this string: `highByte = (textBoxValueI And &HFF00&) / 256`, it's ok with dividing into two bytes. But how to merge it rightly? If I use numbers<0 I have an error here: `number = highByte * 256 + lowByte`

Comment: try this? http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=56

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for the link. It helped. But how to connect these bytes? If i try `number = highByte * 256 + lowByte` here is an error (input<0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare highBite and lowByte as Long instead, and youll be able to merge them

but for low byte i would suggest to use mod operator

```
lowByte = textBoxValueLong Mod 256
```

Comment: It helped but why? lowByte and highByte are in range [0...255] so why it helps to use Long instead of Byte?

Comment: Thanks for explanation! And why you use Mod 256 instead of And &HFF&?

Comment: mod, because lowByte = textBoxValueLong And &HFF& wont produce correct result for negative numbers, long because highbyte contains negative result for negative numbers, which is not allowed for byte( 0...255 only )

Answer (score 1):

If you really need `loByte` and `hiByte` as `Byte`s and must remain within the 2 bytes  integer range, then the following should be the solution:

```
Sub testInteger()

 Dim sTBV As String

 sTBV = "32767"
 'sTBV = "-32768"

 Dim maxI As Integer
 maxI = 127 * 256 + 255
 Dim minI As Integer
 minI = -128 * 256

 If Val(sTBV) >= minI And Val(sTBV) <= maxI Then

  Dim i As Integer
  i = Val(sTBV)

  Dim loByte As Byte, hiByte As Byte

  loByte = i And &HFF&
  hiByte = (i And &HFF00&) / 256

  Dim j As Integer
  j = Val("&H" & Hex(hiByte) & IIf(Len(Hex(loByte)) = 1, "0" & Hex(loByte), Hex(loByte)))

  MsgBox hiByte & ", " & loByte & ", " & j

 Else

  MsgBox "out of integer range"

 End If

End Sub
```

The 2 bytes integer range is from -32768 to 32767 only.